# Nested list (vector of vectors of strings) initialization fails

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017

This code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> & v)
  {
    std::cout << "Vector of string vectors size: " << v.size() << "\n";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      std::cout << "Vector #" << i << " has size " << v[i].size() << "\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass({ { "a" } }); // <--- ok
  MyClass({ { "a", "b" } }); // <--- PROBLEM
  MyClass({ { std::string("a"), "b" } }); // <--- ok
  MyClass({ { "a", "b", "c" } }); // <--- ok
  MyClass({ { "a" },{ "c" } }); // <--- ok
  MyClass({ { "a", "b" },{ "c", "d" } }); // <--- ok
}
```

outputs this (Visual Studio 2017):

```
Vector of string vectors size: 1
Vector #0 has size 1
Vector of string vectors size: 4
Vector #0 has size 97
Vector #1 has size 0
Vector #2 has size 0
Vector #3 has size 0
Vector of string vectors size: 1
Vector #0 has size 2
Vector of string vectors size: 1
Vector #0 has size 3
Vector of string vectors size: 2
Vector #0 has size 1
Vector #1 has size 1
Vector of string vectors size: 2
Vector #0 has size 2
Vector #1 has size 2
```

So, it works OK in all cases except in the case where we have a vector of one vector, containing two strings. It also works in the above case if we explicitly construct std::string from one of the string literals. If both are just plain string literals, the compiler seems to get "confused" and constructs a vector of 4 items, the first of which contains 97 strings. Note that 97 is the character code of "a".

I guess my question is, should the compiler interpret this problematic construction as I'd expect, or is this bad code to initialize a nested list like this?

Comment: FWIW, g++ 6.4.0 says "error: call of overloaded 'MyClass(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous".

Comment: I tried several compilers ... all of them return an ambiguous error

Comment: Notice that `void f(MyClass); f({{"a", "b"}});` is not ambiguous but call the copy constructor of `MyClass`...

Answer (score 17):

The inner vector in `MyClass({ { "a", "b" } })` is creating using range constructor:

```
template <class InputIterator>
  vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

This happens because `{ "a", "b" }` is interpreted not as `std::initializer_list<std::string>` but as a pair of raw pointers.

Answer (score 8):

Stepping into the offending constructor in the debugger reveals that VC++ has picked the `vector<vector<int>>` constructor that takes two iterators (they are `const char*`s in this case).
That is, it treats the construction like

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> {"a", "b"}
```

This, of course, leads to undefined behaviour since the two pointers don't belong to the same array.

As a side note, g++ compiles both of

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> as{{"a", "b"}};
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> bs{"a", "b"};
```

but crashes miserably on the latter, while the former behaves as expected.

VC++ compiles the double-braced variable construction in the way you would expect, so I suspect (hope) that there's a bug in VC++.

Comment: This is a rare case where VC is right. Since UB is invoked, VC could output the fully C++20 compliant source code of VC2020 and still be correct.

Comment: @YSC The behavior is UB, but shouldn't the compiler issue an ambiguous call for the constructors like clang and g++ do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Note that if I just construct a vector like this,

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v2({ { "a", "b" } });

(as in your answer) it works fine, you get a vector including one vector that has two strings. The problem only occurs when this initialization list is used for constructing another class.

Comment: @Holt No [it](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined) [should](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/comp.std.c/ycpVKxTZkgw/S2hHdTbv4d8J) [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Holt That wasn't my intent. I though the very definition of UB answered your question. As soon as UB is reached, anything else doesn't matter. Code after UB is undefined obviously, but code _before_ it is also poisonned. The standard imposes no requirement, so even if the program is ill-formed from another issue, the compiler is not required to issue an eror or a warning.

Comment: UB removed, the compiler must provide a diagnostic for the ambiguous call, yes.

Comment: @YSC I agree, but UB must be involved, and UB code is not involved until overload resolution is made and has chosen the UB constructor (otherwise, most C++ code would be UB). For me, it is not clear if 1) MSVC is right (i.e., the UB constructor is a better match), in which case code is UB, 2) clang and g++ are right, the call is ambiguous, 3) none are right and the first constructor should be called.

Comment: @Holt Hoooo I do get it know. I really didn't get your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that helps to avoid this undefined behavior with VC++. You can define a second constructor like this:

```
MyClass(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &)
{
}
```

Then, the code lines that would give the problem,

```
MyClass({ { "a", "b" } }); // <--- PROBLEM
```

will not compile anymore and will give you the "constructor overload resolution was ambiguous" error, pointing to the problem. You can then typecast the literal to std::string to resolve the issue.